# HTML/CSS "shadow" border?

Tags: html, css, border

I tried looking in Chrome's *Inspect Element,* but I could not find out how this page here [ http://www.mousehuntgame.com/ ] makes a *shadow* type border? On either side of the middle box [with all the page content], it fades to a darker blue, creating a shadow effect.

I want to use that for my website. What's the code? Is it CSS? Thanks!

Comment: You should add screenshot(s) because links may die in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're using an image:

[image]

*(it's actually `1px` high, I just stretched it here for clarity)*

You could do it with [CSS3's `box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/box-shadow), see here for a rough example: http://jsfiddle.net/B9Uyj/1/

To make `box-shadow` work in older versions of IE, you can use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/). (It already works in IE9)

An image would be the easiest option here.

Comment: Yes, and box-shadow is clearly going to become mainstream viable very soon.  http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow

Comment: I checked out the link, and that's pretty sweet. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

if you want CSS3 you can style your text with

```
text-shadow: red 2px 2px 2px;
```

do box shadow with

```
-moz-box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #CCC;
-webkit-box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #CCC;
box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #CCC;
```

for simplicity of background gradients you can use this site
http://gradients.glrzad.com/

Answer (score 2):

This Css code will give solid border to division and Shadow, as used in the page in your link.

```
 -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#F6E7B9;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 4em rgb(4,6,5);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 3em rgb(6,7,8);
    box-shadow:0 0 1em rgb(5,9,2);
    border:20px solid skyblue;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I normally set the background-image of a container to be a whatever x 10 pixel image which would be 20 pixels on each side worth of shadow, and then repeat vertically. Assuming your whitespace is 960px wide with 20px each side of shadow, use:

```
<div class="box">
     content
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.box
{
     background: url(image-with-shadow.png) repeat-y;
     padding: 0 20px;
     width: 960px;
}
```

Here's an example of an image to use: http://projectavian.com/repeat.png

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are doing it with the images. Search 'active' and check out all their stuff in this stylesheet: http://www.mousehuntgame.com/css/en/tabbarview.css?v=98&t=1294342331